# Problem returning object from VB.NET COM Assembly into VBA (Access)

Tags: vb.net, vba, com

I have an assembly in VB .NET 2.0 that I am trying to use to call a webservice.

This will be COM visible, and return the results to Access in VBA.

The .NET Assembly passes all tests and executes perfectly.

I was experiencing "Object does not support this property or method" errors when calling the methods from VBA.

I broke it down to a certain object that was being returned and added some test methods to the .NET DLL.

There is a "Patient" object I want to return.
It looks like this (made it very very simple to test it):

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

<ComClass(Patient.ClassId, Patient.InterfaceId, Patient.EventsId)> _
Public Class Patient

#Region "COM GUIDs"
    ' These  GUIDs provide the COM identity for this class 
    ' and its COM interfaces. If you change them, existing 
    ' clients will no longer be able to access the class.
    Public Const ClassId As String = "672dfbd9-8f3a-4ba2-a33d-89fef868f2b9"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "74a9c54c-4427-4d31-8220-3258ecda345d"
    Public Const EventsId As String = "dc25515e-1bb7-4a66-97d5-270c00d792a9"
#End Region

    Public Sub New()

        MyBase.New()

    End Sub

    Public Property StorePatientID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_StorePatientID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_StorePatientID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_StorePatientID As Integer
End Class
```

So about as simple as an object can be really.

I have a method that just returns a dummy record, just to test it:

```
Public Function GetPatientTest() As Patient
        Dim patient As New Patient

        patient.StorePatientID = 99

        Return patient
    End Function
```

This fails with the afformentioned error.

HOWEVER,

This method succeeds!

```
Public Function GetPatientArrayTest() As Patient()

        Dim strings As New List(Of Patient)
        Dim patient As New Patient

        patient.StorePatientID = 99

        strings.Add(patient)

        Return strings.ToArray

    End Function
```

The DLL is made com visible through "Properties" page.
Builds to project/bin/debug, always do a rebuild.
Always seems to be updated with new methods etc when I look at it in VBA so don't think it's looking at an old version.

Obviously no funny dependencies with these methods.

Really really struggling with this.

EDIT:

Update 16/03/2011 - Added VBA script

```
Public Function FindPatientsTest(ByVal surname As String, ByVal surnameBeginsWith As Boolean, ByVal forename As String, ByVal forenameBeginsWith As Boolean, ByVal dateOfBirth As String)


Dim token As String
token = Login()

Dim patient As SCIStoreWS60.patient
Set patient = New SCIStoreWS60.patient

'// This doesn't work.
'// When adding a "Watch" to the function, I can see it returns an "Object/Patient" and is the correct results
'// When adding a "Watch" to the variable "patient" I can see it is a "Patient/Patient"
patient = sciStore.GetPatientTest()

'// This works fine
Dim something As Variant
something = sciStore.GetPatientArrayTest()

End Function
```

Update 16/03/2011 5 minutes later - Chastising myself

Sorry, I just worked it out.

I need to "Set" the patient variable.

```
Set patient = sciStore.GetPatientTest()
```

Why didn't I need to do this for the "something" variant?

Comment: Post the failing vba code as well.

Comment: Can you also included in your VBA code confirmation your "succeeding" array return actually contains a `Patient` with ID 99 accessible from Access?

Comment: Sure, added the VBA script. I can see through the "watch" that the function is actually returning an "Object/Patient", and the patient it is returning it correct. So appears as though the function is being called correctly. It just looks like VBA is having a problem assigning the result to the variable I am declaring?

Comment: Just worked it out. Needed to "set" the patient variable. Occam's razor. When you start judging the funadmental workings of COM/Visual Basic, you've probably made a daft ommision.

Answer (score 1):

So, yes, you need to `Set` object references, but not arrays.